# Box-sizing: how to get rid of the scrollbar padding in Firefox

Tags: css

Here's a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Sample Textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; background:#D3D3D3;}
textarea {overflow:auto; box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; padding:6px;}
</style> 
</head>  
<body> 
<form action="#">
<textarea rows="1" cols="1">This is some text.</textarea>
</form> 
</body>  
</html>
```

I used the box-sizing property to set the textarea width to 100% plus some padding and it works in all major browsers. However, in Firefox if you add more content to the textarea, you'll see unwanted padding around the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox applies the padding not only to the content but to the scrollbar as well.

Change your `textarea` style definition so that it reads like this:

```
textarea
{
    overflow:auto; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    line-height:26px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
```

This corrects the padding issue, but once there are two or more lines of text it will look somewhat awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the line-height is too much and as you mentioned it looks awkward!