# Right scrollbar causes text to shrink when it is shown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a problem with the y-scrollbar.

My problem is that when i hover the DIV, a y-scrollbar is shown afterward, which this will makes everything in that DIV shrink a bit. How can i avoid this?

**html**

```
<div class="ht ov-h darker-bg p-r-3">

    <h1 class="widget-title p-y-2 p-x-1"> Top Artists </h1>

    <ul class="list-artists p-l-0">
        {{#each artists as |artist|}}
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="link-nostyle">
                <div class="row p-y-1">

                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="{{artist.image}}" class="img-fluid img-circle">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-off-xs-1 col-xs-7 vertical-text">

                        <span> {{artist.name}} </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.widget-title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: $spacer-y;
}

.widget {
  background: #E0EAEC;
}

.ov {
  overflow: auto;
}

.ov-h {
  overflow: hidden;

  &:hover, &:focus {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

.ht {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: force a scrollbar to always be present body{overflow: scroll;}

Comment: Something with the box-sizing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689490/box-sizing-how-to-get-rid-of-the-scrollbar-padding-in-firefox

Comment: @JonasGrumann i want the scrollbar to be present only when the user hover the area

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of options here.

1- You can set the scrollbar to be always visible, using `overflow-y:scroll`

2- You can use jQuery scrollbars, like 'Perfect scrollbar'

3- You can always hide the overflow while hovering, using `overflow-y:hidden` in your `&:hover, &:focus`.

Comment: i think that the second option is the way for me, as i want the scrollbar to be prensent only when the mouse is hover

Comment: You can get it from here [Perfect scrollbar](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/). This custom scrollbar will not force the padding in your DIV.

Comment: thanks you, i will wait to see if there is a better solution without using jquery plugin